# IIS server and Apache server

Tags: apache, iis, solr

I am running Tomcat Apache server for solr and I my web interface is based on IIS. I was wondering if it is possible that I run both IIS and Tomcat server on the same machine and with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run them on different ports and you should be good to go. you can access them through the ports as follows:

```
localhost:80/myIISSite or localhost/myIISSite (default http port)

localhost:8080/myApacheWebsite
```

[Configuring apache to listen on specific ports](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html)

For IIS:

1. Open up IIS Manager.
2. Open the properties windows of Default Web Site.
3. Select the Web Site Tab.
4. Under web site identification, you can change the default 80 port or you can click on  Advance tab and then can change the default 80 port.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, buy they will have to use different ports.  INstall one and start it on the standard ports (80 for http, 443 for https) then install and configure the other to start on another set of ports.